# how to query sqflite multiple whereArgs on flutter?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

How do I query multiple whereArgs? I always return 1 row. it should return 3 rows.

```
final res = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable, 
  where: "name = ?",
  whereArgs: ['read', "uio", 'go'],  
);
```

Answer (score 11):

try to use IN clause:

```
final res = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable, 
  where: "name IN (?, ?, ?)",
  whereArgs: ['read', 'uio', 'go'],  
);
```

**Updated!**

For dynamic `List<String> names` you can try to use this approach:

```
final res = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable, 
  where: "name IN (${('?' * (names.length)).split('').join(', ')})",
  whereArgs: names,  
);
```

Comment: what if its dynamic?

Comment: Both options? maybe you can pass it to IN clause directly -`where: 'name IN (${names.join(', ')})'`

Comment: thx for this, thats a really clean solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating dynamic ? to the where.

```
final res = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable, 
  where: "name IN (${names.map((_) => '?').join(', ')})",
  whereArgs: names,  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may make the query like this:

```
var names = ['read', "uio", 'go'];
final res = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable, 
  where: "name IN (${names.join(',')})",
);
```

whereArgs is an optional argument. If you feel that it is cumbersome to formulate your where-clause by usage of whereArgs, you may make the population by your own code. In this example, it is easier to populate the IN list by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma ","

eg:
UPDATE my_table SET rowOneValue = rowOneValue + 1, rowTwoValue  = rowTwoValue + ( (rowTwoValue / (rowTwoValue) ) + ?) * (v + 1) WHERE value = ?